# JDBC connection pool ping error in Glassfish

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, glassfish-5

I am trying to create a jdbc connection pool in glassfish 5 for a Microsoft SQL Server database. I am using the `mssql-jdbc-6.2.2.jre8.jar` and the latest SQLExpress server version (MSSQL14.SQLEXPRESS)

Resource Type: `javax.sql.DataSource`

Datasource Classname: `com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource`

[image]
[image]
The connection pool is created successfully but when i try to ping, I get this error:

> Ping Connection Pool failed for sql_tire_pool. Connection could not be
>   allocated because: The driver could not establish a secure connection
>   to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption. Error:
>   "Unsupported curveId: 29".
>   ClientConnectionId:f86f1ef8-29c4-4e39-b112-f5da9cbfe13d Please check
>   the server.log for more details.

And this is the server log:

> [2017-10-11T10:55:11.747+0300] [glassfish 5.0] [WARNING]
>   [test.connection.pool.failed]
>   [javax.enterprise.resource.resourceadapter.com.sun.enterprise.connectors.service]
>   [tid: _ThreadID=125 _ThreadName=admin-listener(7)] [timeMillis:
>   1507708511747] [levelValue: 900] [[   RAR8054: Exception while
>   creating an unpooled [test] connection for pool [ test_pool ],
>   Connection could not be allocated because: The driver could not
>   establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets
>   Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: "Unsupported curveId: 29".
>   ClientConnectionId:4c325981-4c97-4db2-b4fb-f7aafca4f03b]]
>
> [2017-10-11T10:55:11.750+0300] [glassfish 5.0] [SEVERE] []
>   [org.glassfish.admingui] [tid: _ThreadID=51
>   _ThreadName=admin-listener(3)] [timeMillis: 1507708511750] [levelValue: 1000] [[   RestResponse.getResponse() gives FAILURE. 
>   endpoint =
>   'http://localhost:4848/management/domain/resources/ping-connection-pool.json';
>   attrs = '{id=test_pool}']]

I am running Windows 10 and also everything is running locally (Glassfish installation, SQL server)

**UPDATE**

Using the accepted answer's solution, the problem is partially solved.The connection pool now successfuly pings the database, but I encounter the same problem as the same error is thrown in the glassfish log when my application tries to run a query through jpa/hibernate.

Comment: It looks like [SSL is mandatory for Microsoft SQL server](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jdbcteam/2008/09/09/the-driver-could-not-establish-a-secure-connection-to-sql-server-by-using-secure-sockets-layer-ssl-encryption/). Silly question: have you tried to a [SSL-enabled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/connecting-with-ssl-encryption) configuration?

Comment: Actually I haven't because at the moment I don't need SSL...
I had no problem connecting to the same db with a glassfish-4 installation though.

Comment: Exact same issue here (unable to upgrade to GlassFish 5.0 because of this, despite it working fine on 4.1.1), were you ever able to get this fixed?

Comment: Sorry, I never got the time to try it out again... I'm stuck with 4.1.1 as well for now..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Facing also this issue with *Glassfish 5* on *Windows 10*, disabling elliptic curves did the trick, just add:

```
-Dcom.sun.net.ssl.enableECC=false
```

to glassfish JVM options and restart server.
posted workaround on glassfish issue tracker to help them fix it quickly

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work in my case.  The errors persist.

Answer (score 0):

this happens when password you have set in phpMyAdmin and in payara console is different, check the password
for that
go to xampp->Apache->config->config.inc.php
check password in that file
and keep the same password in payara or glassfish console.